# Автокомплит json

Tags: javascript, json

Добрый день. Подскажите кто знает. Есть код

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $( "#test" ).autocomplete({
        source: function(request, response){
            $.ajax({
                url: 'http://engine.hotellook.com/api/v2/lookup.json?lang=ru&lookFor=hotel&limit=5',
                data:{ query: request.term },
                dataType: "json",
                success: function(data) {
                    response($.map(data, function(v){
                        var text = v.locationName;
                        return text;
                         })); 
                }
            });
        },
        minLength: 2
    });
  });
```

Jquery и jquery ui подключены но почему то данный код не работает.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Код работает. Но вы не правильно обрабатываете результаты.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#test").autocomplete({
    source: function(request, response){
      $.ajax({
        url: 'http://engine.hotellook.com/api/v2/lookup.json?lang=ru&lookFor=hotel&limit=5',
        data:{ query: request.term },
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data) {
          response($.map(data.results.hotels, function(v){
          //             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
            return v.locationName;
          }));
        }
      });
    },
    minLength: 2
  });
});
```

Подобный код очень просто отлаживать используя Chrome Dev Tools или FireBug.